# .php Random image served as .jpg on external site

Tags: php, image, random

A forum that I post on only allows .jpg, .png and .gif images to be loaded from an external URL. I want to get around this and have a dynamic avatar chosen randomly from a directory on my server but I'm having trouble getting it to work (possibly due to extra checks being carried out on the external site, or an error in my code).

So far I've created a folder named "avatar.jpg" on my server and the code in my index.php file within that folder is as follows:-

```
<?php
$arr=array();
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
$arr[$i]=$i.".jpg";
}
$random=rand(1,6);
echo $arr[$random];
?>
```

I have 6 images in the avatar.jpg folder, named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.

When I run mydomain.com/avatar.jpg it correctly displays a random image source, eg. 5.jpg, but when I enter this URL as my avatar URL on the forum it fails to load and Firebug reports "Failed to load given URL".

Am I missing something from my code to make this work as hoped?

Comment: Copy / paste the url that it's trying to access on your server from the external forum source.

Comment: Check if the forum copies your avatar and serves it from their domain, so your server is probably never used more than once.

Comment: The URL is always called from my server, and when it fails to load the URL shown in firebug is as expected: http://mydomain.com/avatar.jpg :)

Comment: Are you expecting it to output text or are you trying to return an image?

Comment: The forum includes the img src code so I am only trying to output the text. I assume that if I echo out <img src="1.jpg" /> then when its loaded through the forum it would result in something like <img src="<img src="1.jpg">" /> causing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are responding with the text string "$name.jpg" for a .jpg file! You have to set the correct content-type headers and serve the bits and bytes of the actual image file.

Something like:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo file_get_contents($randomFilepath);
```

Comment: Note that if you are returning another format (like .gif), you should then use `image/gif` as the content type. Many browsers will let you get away with screwing that up, but not all...

Comment: In fact you should do more work with headers as well than keeping it dynamic to the file type: You should return a Content-length, and since this is an rotating image you could take some care about browser cache controlling headers.